# PowerShell conversion attempted with .NET class

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I've read a few similar Q&As regarding PS and type conversions, but as far as I can see they're not the same situations.

I am attempting to use RMO classes in a Powershell script, but for some reason it thinks a conversion to the same type is necessary and fails to do so.

The code in question is basically:

```
$conn = New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection" @($server, $dbUsernm, $dbPasswd);

$publicationDb = New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.ReplicationDatabase"
$publicationDb.Name = $dbName;
$publicationDb.ConnectionContext = $conn;
```

(A similar type error occurs if I try to use the two-argument constructor.)

The error is:

```
Exception setting "ConnectionContext": "Cannot convert the "(..snip..)" value of type
"Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection" to type "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection"."
```

So what's going on here? It's clearly trying to convert to the same data types. These aren't defined in PowerShell scripts so shouldn't it be able to track the type? I've also tried casting the variable to `[Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection]` in its declaration and/or in the calls / member set, to no avail.

In case it is relevant, I'm loading the RMO classes this way (which appears to be the only working method, even though from what I understand `LoadWithPartialName` is deprecated):

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.RMO")
```

which says:

```
GAC    Version        Location
---    -------        --------
True   v4.0.30319     C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.RMO\v4.0_14.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\...
```

Does that mean it's v4.x of that class, or that it's a .NET 4.x class? If it is a .NET 4.x class, is that relevant in any way i.e. is that a problem for Powershell?

Comment: How do you load the `ConnectionInfo`? i.e. `[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo")`

Comment: It isn't explicitly loaded. Do I have to load the dependencies manually too?

Comment: I tried adding it; It loads, but I still get the same exception.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't replicate the issue. I had to load both assemblies in order to make the code work. I would try closing PowerShell and re-opening it, and try explicitly loading the `.dll`'s  because it may be a version mismatch, e.g. loading with partial name is loading from the GAC, and what is registered in the GAC. i.e.: load  `[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile('C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.dll')`

Comment: Hold up -- Yours is in Program Files. Are you doing this on the system where MS SQL is installed? The idea for this is to be able to remotely do it from a CI agent, so I'm hoping MS SQL doesn't have to be locally installed. FWIW my version for ConnectionInfo says 2.0.50727..

Comment: Yeah I had to, that was the only place I had the right combination of assemblies to load. Could you confirm that you can run `$conn.connect()` and then `$conn.InUse` returns `True`?

Comment: Yes, the connection itself seems to be fine. Both IsOpen and InUse are true after connecting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194255/discussion-between-hal9256-and-keilaron).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: Summary of troubleshooting: @Keilaron had executed an `Import-Module SqlServer` earlier on in the PowerShell session which caused the odd behavior.

Personally, I wasn't satisfied that a simple restart of the PowerShell session fixed the issue, as this kind of error shouldn't happen. When I did some further digging, I think I discovered the root cause, and discovered that this is a bigger issue that could be easily missed.

First, the code to replicate the discovered behavior:

```
Import-Module SqlServer

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.RMO")

$server = 'MyServer'
$dbuser = 'sa'
$dbPasswd = '1234'
$conn = New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection" @($server, $dbUser, $dbPasswd);
$publicationDb = New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.ReplicationDatabase"
$publicationDb.Name = 'RandomDatabase'
$publicationDb.ConnectionContext = $conn;
```

Two key things happen:

1. The `Import-Module SqlServer` loads the SqlServer `.dll`'s included *with* the module, and **not** the GAC installed modules. This is by design, as the the module is not dependent on SQL Server being installed.
2. The `Microsoft.SqlServer.Rmo.dll` is not a part of, or loaded with the SqlServer module, as there are no Replication commands in the SqlServer module. So to use the Replication commands, we have to manually load that `.dll` ourselves.

The two `.dll`'s that we care about that the `Import-Module SqlServer` transparently imported were the two connection dependent `.dll`'s from the SqlServer PowerShell module location:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile('C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\SqlServer\Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll')
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile('C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\SqlServer\Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlClrProvider.dll')
```

--> **Note:** These `.dll`'s were imported as **64 bit** `.dll`'s.

The RMO `.dll` that we had to manually import, come from the GAC, but essentially come from:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.Rmo.dll"
```

**Note:** This is a **32 bit** `.dll`. This is why we couldn't convert a `"Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection"` to type `"Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection"`. Even though they are the same "type", as in name, their different bitness causes them to be incompatible.

Comment: Specifically: I was unaware importing the module would affect the console running it after execution of the script ended, that it would cause version conflicts (or at least I'm guessing that was happening) despite explicitly loading other assemblies afterwards, and so on. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: I did some more digging, and I believe that I discovered the root issue. See my edits above.

Comment: I appreciate it, though it turns out the fact I was ignoring I didn't have Replication is a problem: It only tries to load it once I call `.Script()` on a publication object.. So I'll have to find some way to get it w/o MS SQL installation (preferably).